# How to dynamically reconfigure Drupal's jQuery-based autocomplete at runtime?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, autocomplete, drupal-6

[Drupal](http://drupal.org/) has a very well-architected, [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)-based [autocomplete.js](http://cvs.drupal.org/viewvc.py/drupal/drupal/misc/autocomplete.js?revision=1.23&view=markup&pathrev=DRUPAL-6). Usually, you don't have to bother with it, since it's configuration and execution is handled by the Drupal form API.

Now, I need a way to reconfigure it at runtime (with JavaScript, that is). I have a standard drop down select box with a text field next to it, and depending what option is selected in the select box, I need to call different URLs for autocompletion, and for one of the options, autocompletion should be disabled entirely. Is it possible to reconfigure the existing autocomplete instance, or will I have to somehow destroy and recreate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for reference, I've thrown together a hack that works, but if anyone can think of a better solution, I'd be happy to hear it.

```
Drupal.behaviors.dingCampaignRules = function () {
  $('#campaign-rules')
    .find('.campaign-rule-wrap')
      .each(function (i) {
          var type = $(this).find('select').val();

          $(this).find('.form-text')
            // Remove the current autocomplete bindings.
            .unbind()
            // And remove the autocomplete class
            .removeClass('form-autocomplete')
          .end()
          .find('select:not(.dingcampaignrules-processed)')
            .addClass('dingcampaignrules-processed')
            .change(Drupal.behaviors.dingCampaignRules)
          .end();

          if (type == 'page' || type == 'library' || type == 'taxonomy') {
            $(this).find('input.autocomplete')
              .removeClass('autocomplete-processed')
              .val(Drupal.settings.dingCampaignRules.autocompleteUrl + type)
            .end()
            .find('.form-text')
              .addClass('form-autocomplete');
            Drupal.behaviors.autocomplete(this);
          }
      });
};
```

This code comes from the [ding_campaign module](http://github.com/kdb/ding/tree/master/sites/all/modules/ding_campaign). Feel free to check out the code if you need to do something similar. It's all GPL2.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at misc/autocomplete.js.

```
/**
 * Attaches the autocomplete behavior to all required fields
 */
Drupal.behaviors.autocomplete = function (context) {
  var acdb = [];
  $('input.autocomplete:not(.autocomplete-processed)', context).each(function () {
    var uri = this.value;
    if (!acdb[uri]) {
      acdb[uri] = new Drupal.ACDB(uri);
    }
    var input = $('#' + this.id.substr(0, this.id.length - 13))
      .attr('autocomplete', 'OFF')[0];
    $(input.form).submit(Drupal.autocompleteSubmit);
    new Drupal.jsAC(input, acdb[uri]);
    $(this).addClass('autocomplete-processed');
  });
};
```

The input's value attribute is used to create ACDB, which is a cache of values for that autocomplete path (uri). That is used in the Drupal.jsAC function to bind the element's keydown, keyup and blur events with triggers the autocomplete ajax operation (which caches its values in the ACDB object for that element), opens popups, etc.

```
/**
 * An AutoComplete object
 */
Drupal.jsAC = function (input, db) {
  var ac = this;
  this.input = input;
  this.db = db;

  $(this.input)
    .keydown(function (event) { return ac.onkeydown(this, event); })
    .keyup(function (event) { ac.onkeyup(this, event); })
    .blur(function () { ac.hidePopup(); ac.db.cancel(); });

};
```

What you'll need to do is change the input's value and also reattach the behavior. You'll reattach the behavior by removing the '.autocomplete-processed' class on the autocomplete text field input element and then call Drupal.attachBehaviors(thatInputElement).

This may not work. Things can go very badly if you attach the same behavior to the same element over and over again. It may be more sensible to create different autocomplete fields and simply hide and show them based on the value of the select. This would still require calling Drupal.attachBehaviors when you hide and display the widget, but the same behavior would remain attached if the switch happened more than once, and you wouldn't risk attaching the same behavior to the element multiple times.

Comment: Well, I by no means a JavaScript expert, but should it not be possible to alter the values in JavaScript instead of the "nuclear" option of destroying and recreating the autocomplete each time?

Comment: as the urls are cached in the abcd[] array, you must reattach the behaviour to update it and if you do that you should unbind() all the previous events bounded to the autocomplete element beforeward.

Comment: I've managed to get unbinding and reapplying the behaviour to work, but does that cause the old autocomplete object to be garbage collected? Otherwise, this'll leak memory. It's probably not a big deal, but it is decidedly unpretty :)

Comment: Note that this is pretty much what the location module does - have a look at location_autocomplete.js for the juicy details.

Answer (score 1):

it should be as simple as dinamically change the "value" of the "hidden" autocomplete 
input element that comes aside autocomplete form fields. ie.

```
$('select#myelement').bind('change', function(e) { 
  if (/* something */) {
    $('input#myelement-autocomplete').attr('value', '/mycustom/path');
  }
});
```

Comment: That does not appear to work. Apparently, the URL is stored somewhere in the JavaScript, and not re-read from the input field.

Comment: Also you need to remove `autocomplete-processed` class from the hidden field and then reattach the autocomplete behavior by calling `Drupal.behaviors.autocomplete(document);`.

Comment: it works but a new url is registered on every change, if 2 times it is re attached, total 3 calls will be made to server

Answer (score 1):

Working solution for Drupal **5**

```
/*
 *  Błażej Owczarczyk
 *  blazej.owczarczyk@gmail.com 
 * 
 *  Name: Autocomplete City Taxonomy 
 *  Description: Hierarchical city selecting (province select and city autocomplete)
 */

var Act = Act || {};

Act.init = function () {
    $('select.act-province').change(Act.provinceChange);        // select with top taxonomy terms    
}

/*
 *  Change event of select element
 */
Act.provinceChange = function () { 
    var context = $(this).parent().parent();              
    var currentTid = $(this).val();
    Act.rewriteURI(context, currentTid);
    Act.unbind();
    Drupal.autocompleteAutoAttach();
};

/*
 *  Changes the value of hidden autocomplete input
 */
Act.rewriteURI = function (context, newTid) {
    var tempArray;
    tempArray = $('.autocomplete', context).val().split('/');
    tempArray.pop();
    tempArray.push(newTid);
    $('.autocomplete', context).val(tempArray.join('/'));    
};

/*
 *  Prevents muliple binding of the same events
 */
Act.unbind = function () {
    $('.form-autocomplete').unbind().parents('form').unbind('submit');
};

$(document).ready(Act.init);
```